# Directed Acyclic Graph including a categorical variable with 20 levels

Tags: regression, cart, many-categories, dag

Is it possible within causal inference using DAGs to sensibly include a categorical variable with 20 levels? I have seen that regression trees can be used in this situation but not in combination with a DAG. We use the DAG to map our assumptions about the causal relationships between the outcome and this categorical variable, as well as a number of other variables that my affect the main causal relationship of interest.

Would the process perhaps follow a two-step procedure?
i) construct the DAG,
ii) setup the regression tree based on the minimal adjustment set?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are after, but have a gander at the chapter on effect modification in Hernán, M. A., & Robins, J. M. (2020). [Causal Inference: What If](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/). Chapman & Hall/CRC. One way that categorical variables may be incorporated into DAGs and structural causal models is to represent and model causal effect heterogeneity (e.g., across subpopulations)..

Comment: Thanks @Alexis, will try and find a copy of that book.

Comment: You mean like the downloadable PDF from the lead author's website I linked in my comment? :D

Comment: Apologies. I assumed as it was a book that it would not be freely available. Thanks.